# Create a simple text secret in Google Cloud Secret Manager using CLI

Tags: node.js, gcloud, google-secret-manager

When using the GUI on Google Cloud Console to create a secret all I needed to provide was the secret name and it's value and I'm done.

However, I would like to use the `gcloud cli` to create simple string secrets.

So far, all the documentations in the docs keep mentioning `--data-file` like below:

```
gcloud secrets create sample-secret --data-file="/path/to/file.txt"
```

How can I use simple strings as the secret value similar to the GUI flow such that I can have a command like

```
gcloud secrets create apiKey "adadadad181718783"
```

Must it always be a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try with this sample command

`printf "s3cr3t" | gcloud secrets create my-secret --data-file=-`

setting the `--data-file=-` flag to "-" will read the secret data from stdin.

You can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/secrets/create#--data-file) for reference